# Uploading JavaScript generated image to Django

Tags: javascript, django, image, forms

I have an image generated on the client side which I want to transfer to the server through a form.  For example, let's say that I have a registration form in which the profile image is generated automatically by JavaScript, and I want to transfer that image to django.

What is the best way to transfer the image binary data to the server when user hit the submit button? what form field should I use?

thanks!

Comment: what have you tried? what do you mean "automatically generated"? do you fetch from a list of images or actually draw one new? did you check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?

Comment: I actually draw something new, so sending an image index won't work.  I tried using a CharField to transfer the binary data but I'm losing some of the data (maybe there is a workaround that?). the file object might be a good idea. is it possible to fake a file upload from javascript without uploading any actual file? - thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found an answer myself, here's the solution in case someone needs it:

In the client side, this is how you get the image from canvas and set it to a form field (a hidden char field):

```
var dataURL = document.getElementById('canvas_id').toDataURL("image/png");
document.getElementById('id_hidden_image_field').value = dataURL;
```

And in django side:

1. add to the form a hidden field called 'hidden_image_field', which will be used to pass the data. this field is a simple CharField. you can add max_length limit to make sure image is in a reasonable size (note: not dimensions but actual size).
2. to parse the image data:

   ```
   import re
   import base64
   dataUrlPattern = re.compile('data:image/(png|jpeg);base64,(.*)$')
   ImageData = request.POST.get('hidden_image_field')
   ImageData = dataUrlPattern.match(ImageData).group(2)

   # If none or len 0, means illegal image data
   if (ImageData == None or len(ImageData) == 0:
       # PRINT ERROR MESSAGE HERE
       pass

   # Decode the 64 bit string into 32 bit
   ImageData = base64.b64decode(ImageData)
   ```

and now ImageData contains the binary data, you can simply save to a file and it should work.

hope this helps.